# AJAX update database on browser exit

Tags: ajax

I have a database with field 'status' which is default 0 when offline and 1 when online. I was wondering if anybody knows a way to update the database in the event of browser close (set the 1 to a 0). It has been suggested that I use a body unload and point to AJAX but i've no idea how to do it...PLEASE help,  thank you...

Comment: Note that there's no really reliable way to do an AJAX call before the window closes - the events fired (onbeforeunload and onunload, IIRC) are forcibly terminated in a very short time. Therefore, some of the clients may not update the database in time. Also, there's no reliable way to determine whether the browser is closing, or just the user is navigating to a different page.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution for browser close event. I faced some issue with `onunload` and `beforeonunload` events. It will be triggered for browser close, tab close, any link click, URL change. So i customized my code like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
          var validNavigation = false;

          // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
          $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 116){
              validNavigation = true;
            }
          });

          // Attach the event click for all links in the page
          $("a").bind("click", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          });

          // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
          $("form").bind("submit", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          });

          // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
          $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
            validNavigation = true;
          }); 

          window.onbeforeunload = function() {                
              if (!validNavigation) {                            
                 var status = 'abandoned';
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: your action URL,
                        data: "status=" + status,
                        success: function(res) {
                        },
                    });
              }
          };
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Piskvor is dead-on. There is no reliable way to find out when a user is actually leaving your site to, for example, go to bored.com - or if they have two windows open that are both viewing your site, and they decide to close one of them. That's why, for the most part, login sessions expire and websites provide "Logout" buttons - to know for sure.

If you did want to explore this route further, it's as simple as creating a javascript function

```
function doAjaxThingy(){

    var qty = document.getElementById(q).value;
    var ajax = getXmlObject();
    var url= '/doAjaxThingy.php';

    if (ajax.readyState == 4 || ajax.readyState == 0) {
        ajax.open("POST", url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function (){
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {    
                alert(ajax.responseText);
            }
        }; 
        ajax.send(null);
    }
}

function getXmlObject() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            return new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
            return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            showError('Status: Cound not create XmlHttpRequest Object. Consider upgrading your browser.','Please Wait');
        }
    }
```

and then let the page know to call that function when it unloads

```
<body onunload="doAjaxThingy();">
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have just tried that, it looks as if AJAX may not work when called from body onunload as it does nothing, thanks again anyway I will keep trying :)

Comment: Actually I THINK I may have worked it out (with your advice(s))...I will post back later if it works as I wanted - Thanks again Piskvor and Dutchie432 I appreciate it loads :)

Comment: I would be curious to see your end result! Good luck. Also, you'll probably want to try again with the `getXmlObject` function that I forgot to include. :-/